# Are there alternatives to sinktop backsplashes and sidesplashes?

Tags: sink, backsplash

I just got a new vanity with a counter top that I am having a hard time finding splashes for.  It's a very nice counter top as is and looks really good just nestled in the corner without any splash at all. I'd really like to just keep it as is.

I guess what I really want to know is what is the point of a splash?  Is it to keep water from going down behind the vanity?  There's caulk to prevent that.  Is it to keep water from damaging the drywall around the sink?  If so, aren't there waterproofing treatments that I could apply to the wall around the sink to keep such damage from occurring?

What are my options here as far as not using a splash and what are the implications of not using them?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like most vanities have somewhat of a rounded edge and a backsplash or sidesplash provides a nice clean place to caulk. A vanity seems to be a place where quite a bit of water can wind up on the counter, so I think it's easier to keep clean if you have a splash. What about some ceramic tile? You could put them right on the sheetrock. As for having a hard time finding a backplash, have you contacted the manufacturer? I bought an American Standard vanity top from Lowe's and I had to call A.S. myself to order the side splash.